# Getting the banshee-extension-soundmenu in 10.04?

Tags: banshee, gnome2

I've tried to install `banshee-extension-soundmenu` which isn't available in my 10.04 repos, so I did some research but couldn't find a repo that offers it for my Ubuntu version.

How can I install it and get the wonderful buttons into my sound menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Ubuntu sound menu, which lets audio players like Banshee add album art and player controls to the menu, was [introduced in Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/uds-m-sound-menu-changes-coming-in-ubuntu-maverick/), so this functionality isn't available in your version of Ubuntu.

The closest you can get to the sound menu extension without upgrading Ubuntu is probably the banshee-extension-appindicator, which is available in the 10.04 repositories.

Comment: I guessed that this was the situation as well, thanks a lot for your help!